# eigenvalues properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I have a question which I do not know how to solve.

$A \in M_{m}( \mathbb{C})$

and

$ \exists r > 0 $ such that $A^{r}=I$

$\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$ and there is no other eigenvalues.

I need to proof that $A = \lambda I$

So $ \forall v \in  V_{\lambda}$  I know that:

$v = I(v)= A^{r}(v)= \lambda ^{r}v$

meaning that $\lambda ^{r} = 1$ and therefore $\lambda = 1$ or $\lambda = -1$

But how can I continue from here ?

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: Is $r$ an integer?

Comment: Yes it is an integer

Comment: A minor correction $\lambda^r = 1 \not\Rightarrow \lambda \in \{-1,1\}$, because $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ need not be real.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First prove that $A$ is necessarily diagonalizable and then use this fact.

Comment: in order to proof that $A$ is diagonalizable I have to proof that  geometric multiplicities of $\lambda$ is $n$. but how can I do that ?

Comment: @wantToLearn Do you know about jordan normal form?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the Primary Decomposition Theorem

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ must be $(x-\lambda)^m$, so the minimal polynomial is of the form $(x-\lambda)^n$ for some $n<m$.  Now, also notice that $A$ satisfies the polynomial $x^r-1$, so that we must have $(x-\lambda)^n|(x^r-1)$.  Use the fact that $x^r-1$ has distinct roots to show that $n=1$.